# Equivalent for ignore_dup_row in DB2

Tags: database, db2, sybase

I have a DB2 stored procedure and trigger which are doing set of insertions.Some of these insert statements might already be present in the table. I am trying to avoid checking for the row before every insert as I believe it might add on to the processing overhead. 
I am trying to find out the DB2 equivalent for 'ignore_dup_row' index attribute which is provided by Sybase. If there is no DB2 equivalent for this what else are the viable options to ignore transaction rollbacks when trying to perform a duplicate insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a merge statement:

```
merge into t as x
using (
    values (...) -- new row
) y (c1, c2, ..., cn)
    on x.[key] = y.[key]
when not matched then
    insert (c1,c2,...cn) values (y.c1,y.c2,...y.cn);
```

If you are inserting rows one by one you can also include a continue handler for '23505' in your stored procedure.

Comment: I am inserting the rows one by one. I can use a handler in the sproc but can i use it in trigger as well ?

Comment: A compound SQL (compiled) statement can contain SQL control statements and SQL statements. Compound SQL (compiled) statements can be used to implement procedural logic through a sequence of SQL statements with a local scope for variables, conditions, cursors, and handlers.

Invocation
This statement can be embedded in a trigger, SQL function, or SQL procedure; or issued through the use of dynamic SQL statements. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-49